# Vector in the complex plane

Tags: plotting, complex

Please tell me how I can make an animation with rotating vectors rather than rotating points.

```
Manipulate[{ComplexListPlot[{2.5 E^(I x), 2.5 E^(I (x + (2 Pi)/3)), 
    2.5 E^(I (x - (2 Pi)/3))}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.025]], 
   PlotRange -> {-3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I}]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}]
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the InputForm of the output of `ComplexListPlot`, you will find that it contains a single `Point` expression containing your three points. You could replace the points in the output of the plotting function with appropriate `Arrow` objects starting at the origin using `ReplaceAll`:

```
plot /. Point[l_] :> Map[Arrow[{{0, 0}, #}] &, l]
```

In your code, this would become:

```
Manipulate[
 ComplexListPlot[{2.5 E^(I x), 2.5 E^(I (x + (2 Pi)/3)), 2.5 E^(I (x - (2 Pi)/3))}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.025]], 
   PlotRange -> {-3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I}
  ] /. Point[l_] :> Map[Arrow[{{0, 0}, #}] &, l],
 {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Instead of "ComplexListPlot" you may use "Graphics" together with "Arrow" like:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Red, 
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, ReIm[#]}] & /@ {2.5 E^(I x), 2.5 E^(I (x + (2 Pi)/3)), 2.5 E^(I (x - (2 Pi)/3))}}, 
  PlotRange -> 3 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}]
```

[image]